# php- error in finding sum of all elements having same array key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this.
I'm trying to find sum of all elements having same array key.

Expected Output: `Array ( [JOHN] => 25000 [SMITH] => 13000 [ALEX] => 40000 [JAMES] => 16000 [ANTONY] => 28000 )`

But what I'm getting is something different.

```
$amounts = array( 'JANUARY' => array('JOHN' => array(2000, 5000, 3000), 'SMITH' => array(2000, 1000, 1000, 6000)), 'FEBRUARY' => array('ALEX' => array(5000, 7000, 4000), 'JAMES' => array(4000, 1000, 3000, 2000)), 'MARCH' => array('ANTONY' => array(7000, 2000, 4000), 'JOHN' => array(3000, 5000, 6000, 1000)), 'APRIL' => array('ANTONY' => array(2000, 4000, 6000, 3000), 'ALEX' => array(7000, 8000, 9000)), 'MAY' => array('SMITH' => array(1000, 2000), 'JAMES' => array(2000, 3000, 1000)) );


foreach($amounts as $key => $value)
{
    $sum=array();
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        $sum[$key1] = array_sum($value1);

    }
    print_r($sum);
}
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
Array
(
    [JOHN] => 10000
    [SMITH] => 10000
)
Array
(
    [ALEX] => 16000
    [JAMES] => 10000
)
Array
(
    [ANTONY] => 13000
    [JOHN] => 15000
)
Array
(
    [ANTONY] => 15000
    [ALEX] => 24000
)
Array
(
    [SMITH] => 3000
    [JAMES] => 6000
)
```

Expected Output: `Array ( [JOHN] => 25000 [SMITH] => 13000 [ALEX] => 40000 [JAMES] => 16000 [ANTONY] => 28000 )`

Comment: Whats is your expected output??

Comment: Array ( [JOHN] => 25000 [SMITH] => 13000 [ALEX] => 40000 [JAMES] => 16000 [ANTONY] => 28000 ) @M A SIDDIQUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$amounts = array( 'JANUARY' => array('JOHN' => array(2000, 5000, 3000), 'SMITH' => array(2000, 1000, 1000, 6000)), 'FEBRUARY' => array('ALEX' => array(5000, 7000, 4000), 'JAMES' => array(4000, 1000, 3000, 2000)), 'MARCH' => array('ANTONY' => array(7000, 2000, 4000), 'JOHN' => array(3000, 5000, 6000, 1000)), 'APRIL' => array('ANTONY' => array(2000, 4000, 6000, 3000), 'ALEX' => array(7000, 8000, 9000)), 'MAY' => array('SMITH' => array(1000, 2000), 'JAMES' => array(2000, 3000, 1000)) );

$sum=array();
foreach($amounts as $key => $value)
{    
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1)
    {
      //check key set or not. if not set then assign value 0. so that you dont get undefine index error
        if(!isset($sum[$key1]))
          $sum[$key1] = 0;
        $sum[$key1] += array_sum($value1);

    }    

}
print_r($sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is close, just need this modification:

```
//initialise this  before foreach, so that it doesn't gets reset in between.
$sum=array(); 
foreach($amounts as $key => $value) {
  foreach($value as $key1 => $value1) {
    //Add the previous sum too, so that it doesn't calculate the new sum
    if(!array_key_exists($key1, $sum)) {
      $sum[$key1] = 0;
    }
    $sum[$key1] += array_sum($value1);
  }
}
//Debug this at the last and not inside the loop.
print_r($sum);
```